# How do I import emails from flash drive to thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

I am needing to import my emails from my flashdrive that had been saved when I was about to delete windows 7. I am using Ubuntu and Thunderbird.

Comment: How did you save the emails?

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird is not Ubuntu specific, it also runs on other operating systems like Windows, so it is likely that you will receive more information on their website and forums than here. It also depends upon the types of email import file that Microsoft or your other old email client outputs.

I will try to answer your question, but it is best you check on the Mozilla Help site linked below for specifics.

By clicking on the settings menu on the right, you can hover over Tools and then click Import, which if you follow the instructions given in the dialog that will appear, will (with luck) be able to import your emails.

Scan around in the Mozilla Thunderbird help site for more specific information on this topic at:

`https://support.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/home`

Sorry I couldn't be of better help.